# how to pin an application to start in windows phone emulator?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am new to windows phone. I have developed a sample windows phone app. Its running fine in emulator . My problem is that I cant find any option to pin the application to start in windows phone emulator?

Comment: Just like you do it in the real device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pin an application by viewing it in the application list (scroll to the right) and then clicking and holding and selecting the Pin To Start menu option that appears.

Comment: ...in exactly the same way that you would when using a real phone